# How to Schedule a start of DMS task by AWS EventBridge via CloudFormation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge, dms

I am creting a cloudformation template. it is creating Database Migration Service Task. I need to do a scheduling of this DMS taks via EventBridge.
I've created following resource in CloudFormation:-

```
DMSStartTaskScheduler:
      Type: AWS::Scheduler::Schedule
      Properties: 
        FlexibleTimeWindow: 
          MaximumWindowInMinutes: 300
          Mode: FLEXIBLE
        Name: DMSStartTaskRule-dev
        ScheduleExpression: cron(30 17 * * ? *)
        State: ENABLED
        Target: 
          Arn: "DMS task ARN"
          RoleArn: !GetAtt EventBridgeIAMrole.Arn
```

But Getting below error:-

> Invalid request provided: dms is not a supported service for a target. (Service: Scheduler, Status Code: 400,

I tried to create the same Scheduler from Console, there it was working but from Cloudformation template it is giving errors. Can anyone suggest solution of it?

Comment: Hi, the solution found :)

Answer (score 0):

DMS tasks via EventBridge? Then It should be something like this.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  scheduler:
    Type: 'AWS::Scheduler::Schedule'
    Properties:
      ScheduleExpressionTimezone: "Europe/Kiev"
      ScheduleExpression: cron(*/5 * * * ? *)
      FlexibleTimeWindow: 
        Mode: "OFF"
      State: ENABLED
      Target: 
        Arn: "arn:aws:scheduler:::aws-sdk:databasemigration:startReplicationTask"
        Input: >-
         {"ReplicationTaskArn":"arn:aws:dms:us-east-1:123456789012:replication-config:BGDRG5FD4LPMFOQ7SIJ2RQATROULLBB3WTJWXYY","StartReplicationTaskType":"start-replication"}
        RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyRoleForEventBridge"
```

PS: I tested and it worked.

Documentation that helped:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/managing-targets-universal.html
https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/1549

Hope it helped!